# probability of error in sampling to estimate sum of a population

Tags: probability, sampling, concentration-of-measure

Given non-negative numbers $$\{m_1, m_2,\dots,m_n\}$$ we have to estimate the sum $$s = \sum_{i=1}^nm_i$$ using sampling (with replacement). If we sample k numbers uniformly at random, then I can estimate the error in the sum being off by some amount t, but I have a problem where the probability of picking the i-th number is proportional to it, i.e. $$Pr[\text{selecting }m_i] = \frac{m_i}{s}$$

Here is what I have done so far:
Let us sample k numbers with replacement. We pick numbers $$m_{i_1}, m_{i_2}, \dots, m_{i_k}$$
The sum of these, $$M = \sum_{j=1}^km_{i_j} \\E[M] = \sum_{j=1}^kE[m_{i_j}] = \sum_{j=1}^k[\sum_{m_i}Pr[m_{i_j} = m_i]m_i] = \sum_{j=1}^k[\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{m_l}{s}m_l] = \sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{l=1}^n\frac{m_l^2}{s}$$
Here I get stuck as to how to apply any concentration bound like Hoeffding's or any other to a statement like $$Pr[|\frac{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^km_{i_j} - s| \geq y] \leq ?$$
As the estimator from the sample for the sum of the population would be $$\frac{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^km_{i_j}$$

Comment: You can get properly sized brackets (or any other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: It's not clear why you expect this sum to be close to $s$. In your penultimate equation, you can perform the sum over $j$ since $j$ doesn't appear in the summand; so $E[M]$ is, as one might expect, proportional to $k$ (and thus not related to $s$).

Comment: I need to check how does this way of sampling differs from uniform sampling.

Comment: In case that was meant to be a response to my comment, I'm afraid I don't understand it.

Comment: The estimator is $$\frac{n}{k}\sum_{i=1}^km_i$$. How to bound the probability of it being off the real sun when sampling is done with this probability rather than uniform probability. That’s the question

Comment: I thought that might be what you meant – but then your last inequality is missing the scaling factor $\frac nk$, right?

Comment: yes but that's just a scaling factor if I can somehow get to something like $$Pr[|\sum_{i=1}^km_i - \sum_{i=1}^nm_i| > t]$$

Comment: You should fix the question (even if it's just a scaling factor) – people shouldn't have to read through the comments in order to understand the question.

Comment: done. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

You can’t get a concentration result here because

$$
E\left[\frac nkM\right]\ne s\;.
$$

For instance, for $m_1=1$, $m_2=2$ and $k=1$, we have $s=3$ but

$$
E\left[\frac nkM\right]=\frac21\cdot\frac13\left(1^2+2^2\right)=\frac{10}3\;.
$$

Comment: that is correct. However we can bound the expectation of the estimator by observing the $$\text{probability of sampling }m_i \leq \frac{\max_i\{m_i\}}{s}$$

Comment: @user3051981: Then perhaps I still don't understand what you're trying to do...

Comment: I have not been able to get anywhere, so it is just an idea. If the maximum among all the number is M, and the minimum is m, then the probability of picking a number is bounded, $$\frac{m}{s} \leq Pr\left[m_i\text{ is selected}\right] \leq \frac{M}{s}$$ So if the sampling probability is p rather than 1/n, may be we can get somewhere.